# UIProgressView won't change value

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am setting the progress to a UIProgressView :

```
[recordingProgress setProgress:seconds/600 animated:YES];
```

The line is in a timer which keeps repeating, and seconds is an integer (int) that varies from 0 to 600. I notice that if I just insert the value of 0.5, the progress bar moves. I tried using float by:

```
float val = seconds/600
```

but it still doesn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that `seconds` is also an `int`, then you won't be getting a floating point value as a result of your division. Cast to a `float` first:

```
float val = (float)seconds / 600.0f;
```

The reason for this is that dividing two `int`s produces an `int`, in this case `0` for values less than `600`. The `600.0f` is there to ensure that the second operand is also treated properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

float value = (float)seconds / 600;